# Precalculating Masks for Performance

Tags: c, performance, bitwise-operators

As part of a project, I need to do Mask calculations inside a big loop (about 10^6 to 10^7 repetitions). I need to keep any number of Least Significant bits (1-8), or any bit at a specific position (7-0, where 7 is the most significant bit). In order not to calculate the Masks in the main code - and for performance, I came up with the following ideas (in each case, the parameter is an unsigned char from 0 to 7):

1) Use two global arrays defined in a header file (say bitops.h):

```
char mask[8] = {1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255};
char position[8] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
```

where we might might have to wait due to memory latency.

2) Calculate the masks using simple operations (via macros):

```
#define mask(x) ((1 << (x + 1)) - 1)
#define position(x) (1 << x)
```

where we will need about 3 clock cycles for mask and only 1 for position.

What do you suggest? Is the second option actually faster, or will the processor cache the constants in advance if I go for the first?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have actual performance problems?

Comment: You can always put the masks in registers and be superfast.

Comment: I can't put the masks in registers, because I have to access them using an index. The index will play the same role as x in the macro.

Comment: The code you posted is almost meaningless. Neither arrays nor macros have any meaningful performance on their own - only their usage does.

Comment: There are two options: either accessing both arrays or calling both macros on each repetition. That's the comparison...

Comment: So the mask can be different across iterations?

Comment: Yes. On each iteration any of the 8 masks on each array can be used.

Comment: Ok, that's a little unfortunate. And where does the `x` come from? What happens with the result? What platform is it for? If x86, is there any chance the table lookup could be done with a `pshufb`?

Comment: Could you elaborate about pshufb? I have no clue what this is! :D

Comment: `pshufb` is an SSSE3 instruction that can be seen as either shuffling bytes according to a table that says for every position which of the 16 bytes goes there (or zero), or equivalently, a parallel 16-byte table lookup that replaces all 16 indices by their values from an 16-byte array simultaneously (actually it replaces the table but you get the idea). It's pretty useful, for example to [emulate popcnt](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html) or to bit-reverse 16 bytes in fewer than 1 cycle per byte (or with a trivial extension, bit-reverse other sizes)

Answer (score 1):

You should really benchmark this to see whether there is a significant difference, but in general the rule of thumb is that for simple calculations (e.g. a few cycles) it's better to do the calculation on-the-fly, while for complicated calculations (10s of cycles or more) a lookup table may be more efficient. It looks like direct calculation would be the way to go in this case, but there are so many other factors to consider that you won't know for sure unless you benchmark.

Comment: Actually the code is part of a steganography algorithm. The data is hidden inside an image. Thus, the faster the better!

Answer (score 1):

I expect the first one will be better because the arrays should always be in the cache. If you want to be sure, you should benchmark it.

But don't even waste your time worrying about this unless you've determined that this loop is a bottleneck. Do it the most clear way first, and if performance is an issue then worry about redesigning it.